# Trigger 2 events on href? Scroll to top, then load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a question, I would like to trigger a specific event in javascript or jquery on a webpage. The page has an animation effect during page loads (the screen and content splits in two and slides open revealing the next content). This works fine when the content on the page fits and doesn't need to be scrolled. However when content needs to be scrolled, the effect doesn't look as good. Is there anyway to trigger an href to scroll back to the top of the page and THEN load the href link/target? In basic terms something like "on click scroll to top and then load link" Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Oh, and there are 5 links on the page, so all should scroll to top and then load their respective links

Comment: Please give more information

Answer (score 0):

One could use jquerys animate to scroll to the top, then if that finished redirect:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow", ()=> location.href = this.href );
  return false;
});
```

[try it](http://jsbin.com/bitoruxape/edit?output)